# tsql trigger behaves abnormally

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger which is as follows:

```
  ALTER TRIGGER [trigger_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] ON [dbo].[tblA]
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF ( UPDATE([CATEGORY_VALUE_ID]))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[htblB]
  ( ID
  , CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
  , STATUS_END_DATE
  , STATUS_END_DATE_SOURCE)
  SELECT
  t.ID
  , t.CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
  , GETDATE()
  , t.UPDATE_SOURCE
  FROM [dbo].[tblCAPITATION] t
  INNER JOIN inserted ins
  ON t.CATEGORY_VALUE_ID = ins.CATEGORY_VALUE_ID 
END
```

What it needs to do is insert a new row in htblB when the column CATEGORY_VALUE_ID is updated. It works fine if only one row is updated. But if it has multiple row updates, then 2 to the power number of rows updated amount of new rows are inserted in htblB.

```
UPDATE dbo.tblCAPITATION
SET CAPITATION_STATUS_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID = '80574', UPDATE_SOURCE = 'TEST3'
WHERE CAPITATION_ID = 2 OR CAPITATION_ID = 3
```

This statement will insert 4 new rows to htblB instead of 2.

May you please shed some light on why this is hapening and how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that ID is the primary key, if so then you should be joining inserted on ID not category_value_id

```
ALTER TRIGGER [trigger_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] ON [dbo].[tblA]
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF ( UPDATE([CATEGORY_VALUE_ID]))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[htblB]
  ( ID
  , CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
  , STATUS_END_DATE
  , STATUS_END_DATE_SOURCE)
  SELECT
  t.ID
  , t.CATEGORY_VALUE_ID
  , GETDATE()
  , t.UPDATE_SOURCE
  FROM [dbo].[tblCAPITATION] t
  INNER JOIN inserted ins
  ON t.ID = ins.ID
END
```

Comment: I think I got it. Because the same value is updated for both. Stupid of me.

Comment: The inserted table gives you the rows that where just updated, you need to join them back to the base table.  You would do that join on primary key or you won't get the correct rows as you saw.  You got all combination of rows that matched on category_value_id instead